# loading spinner dialog on fetching data from database in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android. I just developed an app that displays some data from database on tableview. It takes some time to fetch data. At that time it should display Loadind Spinner. After fetching, it should disappear.

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(result.this, "Retreiving", "Please Wait....");

        butt();
        if(pd.isShowing())
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        else
        {
            pd.show();
        }
        }
    });
```

This is the button event - it is working but it works after fetching it.

Comment: How are you fetching from the DB?

Comment: Yes ji from remote server by method butt()

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity create a Asynctask :

```
private class Load_data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd= ProgressDialog.show(result.this, "Retreiving", "Please Wait....");
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
        publishProgress(param);
        butt();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String arg) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Now call your Asynctask when you click on the button :

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    new Load_data().execute();
});
```

You can check the documentation of Asynctask here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hope it helps